# Setting up a MySQL cluster with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cluster-computing

I have a MySQL cluster containing of 2 servers, replicating between each other.

I would like to setup Laravel's database connection, so it uses both servers, randomly choosing connections per user, so the load is balanced. I'm using Eloquent with query builder.

Is there an out-of-the-box way to combine Laravel and a MySQL cluster?

Comment: You could add both connections to the database.yml `connections` configuration (as `mysql-1` and `mysql-2`, say), and then under `default` just use something like `rand(0, 1) ? 'mysql-1' : 'mysql-2'` maybe?

Comment: Was thinking about it. But is the db connection done on every request? >It would need to be for this to work properly.

Comment: Yes the connection is initialized on every request, but choosing servers at random is not load balancing.

Comment: @Bogdan That's true, but - based on probability - one can assume the query distribution would be 50-50. Does that make sense? I'm just trying to figure out if there's a Laravel-provided way to do this.

Comment: The distribution won't be exactly 50-50, but close enough to not take into consideration. However this only distributes the connections, not the actual load. Most likely requests run a variable number of queries against the database, so one request might run 2 queries while another might run 10, and by sending one to **Server1** and the other to **Server2** you're not actually bancing the load since `2 != 10`.